# Would someone provide an example of extracting data from a char array?

Tags: arduino-nano, c++, array

- I have tried so many things now that I am just confused.
- I am not understanding the way *char arrays* work.
- I can't get the date and names extracted.  And when I use just strings, I jam up the memory.

Below was my last attempt, before asking the question.

```
while (f.available()) {
  String line = f.readStringUntil('\n');

  if (line.startsWith("04-23")) {
    currentDay = 1;
    int str_len = line.length() + 1;
    char char_array[str_len];
    line.toCharArray(char_array, str_len);
    Serial.println(char_array);                 // Everything works to here
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      b += char_array[j];
    }
    bMth = b.toInt (); // This should be an int of the birth month in this case: 04
  }
}

Var:
format: MM-DD-YYYY,Name  // this is inside the file
line = "04-23-2020,James"  // This is the output from - Serial.println(char_array);
```

**What I am trying to do is**

- Extract the month/day so that I can compare it to today.
- The year so I can calculate the age.
- The name to display on OLED.
- Everything else seems to work, but I can't get my head
  wrapped around the **char array** access.

To do this in PowerShell I would do:

```
$line = "04-23-2020,James"

$dob = ($line.Split(","))[0]
$bMth = ($dob.Split("-"))[0] # This is not used in this example
$bDy = ($dob.Split("-"))[1]  # This is not used in this example
$bYr = ($dob.Split("-"))[2]

$age = $(get-date -UFormat %Y) - $bYr

Clear-Host
Write-Host (@'
Name: {0}
Age:  {1}

'@ -f $($line.Split(","))[1], $age)
```

In Python:

```
import datetime as dt

line = "04-23-2020,James"

dob = (line.split(',')[0])
bMth = (dob.split("-"))[0] # This is not used in this example
bDy = (dob.split("-"))[1]  # This is not used in this example
bYr = (dob.split("-"))[2]

age = int(dt.datetime.now().year) - int(bYr)

print('Name: ',(line.split(',')[1]))
print('Age: ', age)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://majenko.co.uk/blog/splitting-text-c

Comment: I recommend learning how to use the `strtok()` function. It is also described in Majenkos blog entry

Answer (score 1):

When working with Arduino, [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) is your friend. Scroll down and look on the left side under **(string.h)**. Lot's of great `char` functions there. Other useful functions such as `iota()` - [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/).

Here's one way to accomplish the parsing of the input data.

```
// Sketch uses 2064 bytes (6%) of program storage space.
// Global variables use 323 bytes (15%) of dynamic memory.
// Arduino IDE 1.8.9.
char line[] = "04-23-2020,James";
char Name[100];
unsigned int Month, Day, Year;

// Make an attempt to validate the input data.
byte Counter = 0;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  char * pch = strtok(line, "-,");

  while(pch != NULL){
    if(Counter == 0){Month = atoi(pch);}
    else if(Counter == 1){Day = atoi(pch);}
    else if(Counter == 2){Year = atoi(pch);}
    else if(Counter == 3){strcpy(Name, pch);}
    pch = strtok(NULL, "-,");
    Counter += 1;
  }

  // Print out the data.
  if(Counter == 4){
    Serial.println(Month);
    Serial.println(Day);
    Serial.println(Year);
    Serial.println(Name);
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Error");
  }

}

void loop(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [sscanf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) if your data format is fixed, something like this:

```cpp
char line[] = "04-23-2020,James";
int day, month, year;
char name[100];
if (sscanf(line, "%d-%d-%d,%s", &month, &day, &year, name) == 4)
{
    // Process the four items.
}
```

Comment: but the code for scanf takes 1.5kB flash memory